# Adding extra column to reduce complex queries

Tags: mysql, join

Let's look at two tables, for example tables  `Post` and `User`
In `Post` table, column *user_id* is foreign key.

**Table** `Post`
 
*-id*
*-user_id*
*-post*

**Table** `User`
*-userID*
*-username*
If we want to get poster's username, we have to use `join` query and get it from `User` table.

Wouldn't it be easier that we add extra column in `Post` table for storing posters' usernames in order to simplify SQL queries. In this case, `Post` table would have *user_id* and *username* columns (*username* column is redundant) but that would eliminate `join` queries for catching posters' usernames.

What is the best choice, to store usernames in `Post` table or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a view is an opition: and ust query that view. However, views in msql don't offer as much benefit in terms of performance as they once did.

It might be that just running the join is fine. Depending on the amount of data you will eventually store you may need to consider other means to improve performance such as partitioning tables etc etc. - but that is for down-the-line

Answer (score 0):

Adding redundant data to the DB is not a good choice.

If you really have to simplify your select queries then create a view for that case. That way the data is in one place and you don't need to join every time. But a simple join is actually not that big a deal.